# xe:beanNamePicker, cant get my values from a notes view into result set

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have set up a java class that I want to use for an xe:beanNamePicker. Somehow I am not able to add a created SimplePickerResult into the result set.

```
package se.myorg.myproject.app;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import se.sebank.namis.utils.Utils;

import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.DocumentCollection;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.View;

import com.ibm.xsp.complex.ValueBindingObjectImpl;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.picker.data.INamePickerData;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.picker.data.IPickerEntry;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.picker.data.IPickerOptions;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.picker.data.IPickerResult;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.picker.data.SimplePickerResult;

public class DirectoryNamePicker extends ValueBindingObjectImpl implements INamePickerData {

    private Utils utils;

    Properties props;

    public DirectoryNamePicker(){
        //constructor
        utils = new Utils();
        utils.printToConsole(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString() + " - DirectoryNamePicker() // constructor");
        try {
            props = utils.getDataSourceProperties();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  public String[] getSourceLabels () {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

  public boolean hasCapability (final int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
  }

  public List<IPickerEntry> loadEntries (final Object[] arg0, final String[] arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public IPickerResult readEntries (final IPickerOptions options) {
    String startKey = options.getStartKey();
    int count = options.getCount();
    TreeSet<IPickerEntry> entries = new TreeSet<IPickerEntry>();
    if (startKey != null) {
        // User is performing a search
        try {
          entries = this.dirLookup(startKey, count);
        } catch (NotesException e) {
          System.err.println("Exception trying to perform directory lookup: " + e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    return new SimplePickerResult((List<IPickerEntry>) entries, -1);
  }

  public TreeSet<IPickerEntry> dirLookup(final String search, final int limit) throws NotesException {
    TreeSet<IPickerEntry> result = new TreeSet<IPickerEntry>();

    String server = props.getProperty("server_notesname");
    String filepath = props.getProperty("db_project_data");
    Database db = utils.getSession().getDatabase(server, filepath);

    View vw = db.getView("vw_all_todo_namespicker");
    vw.setAutoUpdate(false);

    DocumentCollection dc = vw.getAllDocumentsByKey(search, false);
    int count = 0;
    Document tmpdoc;
    Document doc = dc.getFirstDocument();

    while (doc != null && count < limit) {
        String person = doc.getItemValueString("app_ProjMgrName");
        IPickerEntry entry = new SimplePickerResult.Entry(person, person);
        result.add(entry);
        // result.add(entry does not seem to work
        tmpdoc = dc.getNextDocument();
        doc.recycle();
        doc = tmpdoc;
        count = count +1;
      }    
    vw.setAutoUpdate(true);
    return result;
  }

}
```

Is there anyone that can tell me what I m doing wrong? I have choosen a treeset instead of an arraylist. this is because I go to a view with lots of multiple entries so I do not want duplicates and have it sorted by values.

Comment: Does it work if you do a search in the name picker dialog? Your code only returns a filled result set when searching.

Comment: yes it does a search. if I print out the amount of docs in my document collection I see it has found matching documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're casting TreeSet to (List) at the line:

```
return new SimplePickerResult((List<IPickerEntry>) entries, -1);
```

because the SimplePickerResult needs a List (it won't accept a Collection), but TreeSet does not implement List, so that cast will fail.
You'll probably have to change it back to an ArrayList. 
To sort, try using java.util.Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c) with a custom comparator that compares the entry.getLabel() value, as SimplePickerResult.Entry doesn't have an in-built compare method.